# Docker/zookeeper Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

Good Day,

I wanted to test the config store which is built using spring boot. The instruction given to me is run the project using docker-compose.yml files. I'm new with this,I've tired to execute but while running those commands on iMAC terminal I'm facing the following exception.

```
platform-config-store    | 2018-03-05 11:55:12.167  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@22bbbe6
platform-config-store    | 2018-03-05 11:55:12.286  INFO 1 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
platform-config-store    | 2018-03-05 11:55:12.314  WARN 1 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

platform-config-store    | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
platform-config-store    |  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
platform-config-store    |  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
platform-config-store    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6-1569965]
platform-config-store    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6-1569965]
platform-config-store    | 
platform-config-store    | 2018-03-05 11:55:13.422  INFO 1 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
platform-config-store    | 2018-03-05 11:55:13.424  WARN 1 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

I've googled this problem and on some posts it was mentioned that zookeeper client server is not available that's why this error is occurring. So for this I've configured the zookeeper local instance on my machine and made changes in `docker-compose.yml` file. Instead of getting the image from docker, I tried to get it from local machine. It didn't work and faced the same issue.

Also some of them posted that this related to the firewall. I've verified and firewall's turned off.

Following is the `docker-compose` file I'm executing.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: docker.*****.net/zookeeper
    #image: zookeeper // tired to connect with local zookeeper instance
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p3rmission
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis 
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

Could anyone please guide me, what I'm missing here. Help will be appreciated. Thanks